# How to get the average from multipe columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with the first row as header and the first column with student names, the rest of the cells have different student scores.

I have to, on column O create a new header that says Average Score. Once that is done I have to calculate all the values from Columns B to Column N and then print out the average on each row of Column O.

```
Sub CalculateAverage()
Dim rng As Range
Dim totalsum As Double
Dim totalnum As Double
Dim answer As Double
    totalsum = 0
    totalnum = 0

Set rng = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

    For Each Sheet In Application.Worksheets
    Sheet.Cells(1, 15) = "Average Score"
    ActiveSheet.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    Next

    For Each Sheet In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:N502").Cells
        totalsum = totalsum + Sheet.Value
        totalnum = totalnum + 1
    Next

    answer = totalsum / totalnum
    Average = answer
    Range("O2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Average()
End Sub
```

I am getting a debug error on the second last line.Can Anyone help me figure this out. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.. I just added an end after the second For statement. The code doesnt show any errors anymore bu it also does not do anything...m I doing something wrong?

Comment: Change “For Each Sheet” to “For Each rng” and remove the parenthesys: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Average

Comment: Why don'y you use a worksheet formula instead?  `=AVERAGE(B2:N502)` or if it must be in VBA for some reason: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(B2:N502)`  Am i missing something?

Comment: @DisplayName just did that and it showing me a debug error 13 mismatch on the first for each statement

Comment: @ashleedawg I need to make it so that even when I add more rows, the macro will run and do averages in column O

Comment: Instead of using cell references in your ranges, use Named Ranges - this should make your code easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    With Range("O2")
        .Formula = "=AVERAGE(RC[-13]:RC[-1])"
        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("O2:O" & rng.Rows.Count)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: WOW that worked, could you explain what AVERAGE(RC[-13]:RC[-1]) is doing exactly?

Comment: It's called R1C1 notation, and is how Excel natively works out what row and column you want to reference. the [-13] by the C says "Go 13 columns to the left". The lack of any such square bracket says "Just use the current row". I could have just as easily used `Formula = "=AVERAGE(B2:N2)"` but I simply recorded a macro and recorded the resulting code, and R1C1 notation is what Excel uses under the covers.

Comment: If this solves your issue satisfactorily, please click the "Accept" option.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this I would unpivot the data, make a PivotTable out of it, and use the PivotTable. I'd use PowerQuery to do this if I had the addin installed (and it's baked in to Excel 2016). Otherwise I'd use one of the approaches in my answer at [convert cross table to list to make pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252860/convert-cross-table-to-list-to-make-pivot-table/47253398#47253398) and then I'd simply fire up the macro recorder, make the pivot, then view and amend the resulting code.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input but I am only supposed to use VBA for this and cant record any macros. thanks